# aws-java sdk dependency issue with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, aws-java-sdk

I m getting "Failure to transfer com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries:jar:1.11.22 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 " error when I add dependency of aws-java skd in my pom file.
Below is the dependency I m adding.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
<version>1.11.558</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Official Github page [link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java);

```
Importing the BOM


<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.559</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Using the SDK Maven modules

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ec2</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
   <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```